# SharePoint Vs OneDrive

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business

My organization is trying to decide whether to have SharePoint or One Drive as a document repository and would like to know what works better considering the below scenarios.

If the person in corporate has files stored in One Drive as a part of the O365 suite and if he leaves the organization what happens to the files.

Do they disappear? or still exist

I know for a fact that if the person has files in SharePoint the files stays even if he leaves the organization.

Please advise.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a person's license is removed, after 30 days (configurable) their OneDrive will be deleted from the environment. If the user has a manager listed, they will receive an email informing them about this. They will have an opportunity to browse the user's OneDrive and pull any important information.

OneDrive is for personal business files. You may share them with an individual or 2 while drafting the document. Once complete, the process flow should be to move them to an appropriate SharePoint site for longer term storage and disposition.

Answer (score 2):

When an employee account deleted, The OneDrive Clean Up Job runs, and the user profile is marked for deletion. The profile will be preserved in the database in a deleted state. The default retention period is 30 days but this value can be modified by using the `-OrphanedPersonalSitesRetentionPeriod` parameter for the `Set-SPOTenant` cmdlet in the SharePoint Online Management Shell. For more information about the `Set-SPOTenant` cmdlet, check [enter link description here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161390.aspx)

Since OneDrive for Business is built on top of SharePoint’s architecture, you’ll need to [add the manager as a co-owner of the user’s SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-administrators-for-a-site-collection-9a7e46f9-3fc4-4297-955a-82cb292a5be0). The manager will then be able to search for and retain important resources like the deprovisioned user’s OneDrive for Business files.

Find following compassion between One-Drive and SharePoint.

---

**Ownership**
OneDrive

- It's your file. You'd like to keep it private.

SharePoint

- The file belongs to the group.

---

**Permissions Management**
One Drive

- You want to control who has access to your file.

SharePoint

- Permission Management is centralized and controlled by the people in charge.

---

**Collaboration**
One Drive

- Lightweight collaboration.
- You are not quite sure if it's a project yet.

SharePoint

- You will be collaborating with others.
- You need more than a document repository like mailbox, custom lists, web pages, etc.
- You need advanced document features like metadata entry customized views. Etc.

Comment: Thank You @asim nadeem for the detailed description as well

Answer (score 1):

Ideas for a business policy:

OneDrive and SharePoint are both digital storage areas, 
but they serve a different purpose.

OneDrive for Business I compare to a private desk drawer at the office.
A place to store your personal work related stuff in, notes, doodles, ideas, maybe one or two photographs of your family and your dog. Officially it's private, but do know that you're at work and while it's bad form to peek, people might look there, even if it's locked, especially if some kind of calamity happens. So don't hide any secrets in a work related storage space. Work is work.

Things that are strictly home stuff you don't put in a drawer at work,
don't do it either in a digital drawer which is the OneDrive.

Things that belong to home, you do at and keep at home, not at work. 
In digital form: store private files in a home related cloud solution 
that is your own, disconnected from your work life.

Also don't hide things in a hidden drawer that are needed elsewhere 
in the company. In essence, if the private desk drawer and the OneDrive 
are thrown away, no essential business data may be lost.

As a policy, people should use OneDrive for things that are handy (or fun), 
but in the end can be missed if they accidently get thrown away.

SharePoint is where you put everything else. In physical form it would be the central office cabinet of your department. The important stuff, the notes 
and documents that need to be there. Anything that your colleagues might need goes there.

Hope this is helpful.